# coding problem error because of illegal start of expression

Tags: java

```
public class CelsiusTemperatureTable{
    public static double celsius( double FahrenheitTemperature) {
        for( double fDeg = 94; fDeg <= 104; fDeg+=0.5 )
         
         
        public static void displayHeader(); {
         System.out.println("Fahrenheit temperature");   
     }
    
     public static void main( String [] args ) {
         displayHeader();
         double celsiusEquivalent;
         for( double currentFahrenheitTemperature = 94; currentFahrenheitTemperature <= 104; currentFahrenheitTemperature++ ){
             celsiusEquivalent = celsius( currentFahrenheitTemperature );
            System.out.printf ("%.1f\t\t\t\t%.2f\n" ,currentFahrenheitTemperature, celsiusEquivalent );
         }
     }
}
```

coding problem error because of illegal start of expression  where public static void displayHeader();

Comment: You appear to be trying to define a static method in the middle of a for-loop. Whatever you meant to do, that is not the way to do it.

Comment: There are many issues with your code snippet.  

1) Inside the method `celsius()` you want just the conversion formula (`return (fahrenheitTemperature - 32)*5/9;`), not a `for` loop.

2) The declaration of method `displayHeader()` cannot stay inside another method. You should take it out. 

3) There is a `;` between `displayHeader()` and `{`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code. try this one :

```
public class CelsiusTemperatureTable{
    public static double celsius( double FahrenheitTemperature) {
        return (FahrenheitTemperature-32)*5/9;
     }
         
    public static void displayHeader() {
     System.out.println("Fahrenheit temperature");   
    }
    
     public static void main( String [] args ) {
         displayHeader();
         double celsiusEquivalent;
         for( double currentFahrenheitTemperature = 94; currentFahrenheitTemperature <= 104; currentFahrenheitTemperature++ ){
             celsiusEquivalent = celsius( currentFahrenheitTemperature );
            System.out.printf ("%.1f\t\t\t\t%.2f\n" ,currentFahrenheitTemperature, celsiusEquivalent );
         }
     }
}
```

there was no need in the for loop inside the function `celsius()`, you have added a `;` while defining the function, a thing to avoid, you were defining a function inside another and you had a problem with brackets.